# Anime-js hover animation flashing when moving too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am using the anime-js animation library to grow a div on hover and shrink the div when moving the mouse off. Here is the documentation for this library:
http://anime-js.com/documentation/#customEasingFunction

The animation is working perfectly when you move slowly and wait for each animation to finish before moving the mouse but you you are to hover over and then quickly move the mouse away before the 'grow' animation has finished it will flash at the end of the 'shrink' animation and visa versa.
Here is a codepen example of what I mean:

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Fergtato/pen/rmVYqq

HTML

```
<div id="btn" class="btn"></div>
```

JS

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    var animate = anime({
        targets: '#btn',
        width: 1000
    });
});

btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    var animate = anime({
        targets: '#btn',
        width: 500
    });
});
```

(on my actual website I am using the jQuery hover() function but I was not sure how to add jQuery to codepen, plus it has the same problem with vanilla js anyway)

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: It seems to be an abnormality, caused by your anime engine. I do not know how the anime engine works, but I had a problem of this kind with showing and hiding an image when I passed the mouse. The solution was to create a timeout between the mouse event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the elements from the animation before animating them again, otherwise the old animation will continue playing on top of the new one.

Add

```
anime.remove('#btn');
```

before each animations inside your `mouseover` / `mouseout` functions.

Also note that the `mouseover` event will be triggered every time the user move the mouse over the button. `mouseenter` is more apropriate in this case.

Comment: It would be great if you could show an example of how you would accomplish that.